# When do you use Double Angle Brackets in Pdf Code?

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to understand double angle brackets (<<...>>) in Pdf code,
and can't quite understand when, and when not to use them.

This Dictionary Object (is that what it is actually called?) code **works**.

```
42 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 3 0 R
    /Contents 43 0 R
    /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
    /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
    /Resources
        <<
            /ExtGState
                <<
                    /GS  <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                    /GS0 <</ca 0    /CA 0    >>
                    /GS1 <</ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 >>
                    /GS2 <</ca 0.5  /CA 0.5  >>
                    /GS3 <</ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 >>
                    /GS4 <</ca 1    /CA 1    >>
                >>
            /Font
                <<
                    /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                    /Fnt2 7 0 R 
                    /Fnt3 9 0 R 
                >>
        >>
>>
endobj
```

This does **not**.

```
42 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 3 0 R
    /Contents 43 0 R
    /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
    /CropBox [0 0 612 792]
    /Resources
        <<
            /ExtGState
                <<
                    /GS  /ca 1    /CA 1   
                    /GS0 /ca 0    /CA 0   
                    /GS1 /ca 0.25 /CA 0.25 
                    /GS2 /ca 0.5  /CA 0.5 
                    /GS3 /ca 0.75 /CA 0.75 
                    /GS4 /ca 1    /CA 1   
                >>
            /Font
                <<
                    /Fnt1 5 0 R 
                    /Fnt2 7 0 R 
                    /Fnt3 9 0 R 
                >>
        >>
>>
endobj
```

What are the rules regarding **when** and **when not** to use them?

Comment: Well, you use them whenever you write a direct dictionary objects (except **null**). Otherwise you don't.

Comment: OK but if I change the /Font part to include double angle brackets like so -----            /Font
                <<
                    /Fnt1 <<5 0 R >>
                    /Fnt2 <<7 0 R >>
                    /Fnt3 <<9 0 R >>
                >>----- It does not work-----Why is /ExtGState handled differently than /Font?

Comment: To expand a little; ExtGState objects are required to be dictionary objects, so this syntax: "/GS << /ca 1 /CA 1>>" defines a key/value pair (in a Resources dictionary). The key is /GS and the value is a dictionary, so that's valid. This syntax: "/GS /Ca 1 /CA 1" is incorrect, because the value associated with '/GS' isn't a dictionary (its a name object) also there are an odd number of components. The ExtGState Resources dictionary is a dictionary (obviously) and dictionaries contain pairs of keys and values. So an odd number is invalid. Also, in PDF, keys must be name objects (begin with '/')

Comment: *"If I change the /Font part to include double angle brackets like so ----- /Font << /Fnt1 <<5 0 R >> /Fnt2 <<7 0 R >> /Fnt3 <<9 0 R >> >>"* - fonts are described by dictionaries, true, BUT here they are _indirect_ dictionaries, not direct ones.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers! ----- This is very confusing to me... hopefully this will sink in, as I fool some more.

Comment: *"Is the value after /Font (also a key I presume?) not considered a dictionary?"* - It starts with a `<<`, so it is a direct dictionary.

Comment: <</Font /Fnt1 <<5 0 R>>....>> doesn't look valid to me. Although the value associated with /Fnt1 is a dictionary (<< 5 0 R>>) that is not a valid dictionary. The indirect reference to object 5 ( '5 0 R') will resolve to some single object, presumably a dictionary. So what you will end up with is a dictionary which contains **only** a dictionary (notionally "<</Font /Fnt1 << << ....>> >> .....>>"). You can't do that because dictionaries must contain key value pairs. and the dictionary associated with /Fnt1 now only contains a single component, a dictionary and no key.